# i don't manage to push a docker image into openshift docker registry

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-registry

Hello we are using openshift-origin to deploy and run our docker springboot applications.
We'd like to push from maven and from central builder engine our images to private openshift docker-registry.

But actually i manage to login from master node, but i'm not able to login to the docker-registry externally.

I  created pod, service and route for exposing the docker-registry but doesn't work

**Example KO**

```
docker login -u admin -p ftt9woC6CYavh4tnCmKdUe4-y-Vr3EVmTIxNnSuZY9g -e  admin@siav.it docker-registry.os.siav.it

Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint <<https://>>docker-registry.os.siav.it/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint <<https://>>docker-registry.os.siav.it/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get <<https://>>docker-registry.os.siav.it/v2/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get <<https://>>docker-registry.os.siav.it/v1/_ping: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid.
If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry docker-registry.os.siav.it` to the daemon's arguments.
In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-registry.os.siav.it/ca.crt
```

**Example OK**

```
[root@sitorimstlx01 customconfig]# docker login -u admin -p ftt9woC6CYavh4tnCmKdUe4-y-Vr3EVmTIxNnSuZY9g -e  admin@siav.it 172.30.31.250:5000
WARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json
```

Login Succeeded

**Useful data
POD**

```
oc describe pod docker-registry-2-6ewdd 
Name:       docker-registry-2-6ewdd
Namespace:  default
Node:       sitorimstlx01.jarvis.net/192.168.36.1
Start Time: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 09:23:26 +0200
Labels:     deployment=docker-registry-2,deploymentconfig=docker-registry,docker-registry=default
Status:     Running
IP:     10.1.0.2
Controllers:    ReplicationController/docker-registry-2
Containers:
  registry:
    Container ID:   docker://31d147215a526d09c6f120760a466313d172cd5953f0cf79806f2bf26767c32a
    Image:      openshift/origin-docker-registry:v1.2.0-rc1
    Image ID:       docker://0d167b277299b9aa6084cd74ae64e2cc9f6a1968f7a999e0aad580da1adcb02f
    Port:       5000/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:      BestEffort
      memory:       BestEffort
    State:      Running
      Started:      Fri, 17 Jun 2016 12:05:26 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Fri, 17 Jun 2016 09:23:30 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 17 Jun 2016 12:05:06 +0200
    Ready:      True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:5000/healthz delay=10s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:5000/healthz delay=0s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables:
      OPENSHIFT_CA_DATA:    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
--
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

      OPENSHIFT_CERT_DATA:  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
--
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

      OPENSHIFT_INSECURE:   false
      OPENSHIFT_KEY_DATA:   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
--
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

      OPENSHIFT_MASTER:     https://sitorimstlx01.jarvis.net:8443
      REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR:   :5000
      REGISTRY_HTTP_NET:    tcp
      REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET: ePV81gcWaS2dXY8qX5V0nbl0TEod5lkhvn5pr6WZj/w=
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Ready     True 
Volumes:
  registry-storage:
    Type:   EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium: 
  v1:
    Type:   PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  dock-reg-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  registry-token-mq5cv:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: registry-token-mq5cv
No events.

**Service**
oc describe service  docker-registry 
Name:           docker-registry
Namespace:      default
Labels:         docker-registry=default
Selector:       docker-registry=default
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         172.30.31.250
Port:           5000-tcp    5000/TCP
Endpoints:      10.1.0.2:5000
Session Affinity:   ClientIP
No events.

**Route**
oc describe route docker-registry-route 
Name:           docker-registry-route
Created:        2 minutes ago
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:        <none>
Requested Host:     docker-registry.os.siav.it
              exposed on router router 2 minutes ago
Path:           <none>
TLS Termination:    <none>
Insecure Policy:    <none>
Service:        docker-registry
Endpoint Port:      <all endpoint ports>
Endpoints:      10.1.0.2:5000
```

What is wrong ?
Thanks in advance, 
Best regards

Comment: You seem to have included admin passwords, etc. in your post. I hope those aren't real.

Comment: I would recommend to look at the documentation about securing and exposing your registry.